# Error while defining a variable as time.time()

Tags: python, time

I am making a code to change a variable using "random" functions in each iteration, constantly checking if the variable equals a specific, predefined value. When equal, the code stops, recording the amount of time needed to reach the value. The code worked fine and as expected until I introduced my method of timing, using time.time().

Why do I get an error claiming that my syntax in the line "start = time.time()" is invalid (line 5)?

I have tested the same setup in other codes and it works perfectly. How can I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
import random
import time
VARIABLE = int(random.randint(1, 16))
function = int(0)
start = time.time()
while True:
  function = int(random.randint(1,16))
  if not VARIABLE == int("0"):
    if function == int("1"):
      VARIABLE = int(VARIABLE) + int(random.randint(1,1000))
    if function == int("2"):
      VARIABLE = int(VARIABLE) - int(random.randint(1,1000))
    if function == int("3"):
      VARIABLE = int(VARIABLE) * int(random.randint(1,1000))
    if function == int("4"):
      VARIABLE = int(VARIABLE) / int(random.randint(1,1000))
    if function == int("5"):
      VARIABLE = int(random.randint(1,1000)) / int(VARIABLE)
    if function == int("6"):
      VARIABLE = int(VARIABLE) + int(random.randint(1,1000))
    if function == int("7"):
      VARIABLE = int(random.randint(1,1000)) - int(VARIABLE)
    if function == int("8"):
      VARIABLE = int(VARIABLE) ^ int(random.randint(1,1000))
    if function == int("9"):
      VARIABLE = int(random.randint(1,1000)) ^ int(VARIABLE)
    if function == int("10"):
      VARIABLE = (int(VARIABLE) * int(random.randint(1,1000)))^2
    if function == int("11"):
      VARIABLE = (int(VARIABLE) + int(random.randint(1,1000)))^2
    if function == int("12"):
      VARIABLE = (int(VARIABLE) - int(random.randint(1,1000)))^2
    if function == int("13"):
      VARIABLE = (int(VARIABLE) / int(random.randint(1,1000)))^2
    if function == int("14"):
      VARIABLE = (int(random.randint(1,1000))/int(VARIABLE))^2
    if function == int("15"):
      VARIABLE = (int(random.randint(1,1000)) - int(VARIABLE))^2
    if function == int("16"):
      VARIABLE = (int(VARIABLE) ^ int(random.randint(1,1000)))^2
    if function == int("16"):
      VARIABLE = (int(random.randint(1,1000))^int(VARIABLE))^2
  print int(VARIABLE)
  time.sleep(.75)
  if VARIABLE == int("42"):
    end = time.time()
    print("Task completed.")
    break
print("This time, we completed the task in "+(end-start)+ "seconds.")
```

Comment: In python 2 I see no syntax error.  In python3 there are missing parens for `print int(VARIABLE)` (should be `print(int(VARIABLE))`).  python2 runs for a while and eventually spits out some zeros.  There's quite a few idiomatic issues with your program (`int("42")` -> `42`) and `^2` is not squared but `xor` -- not sure where to go with this and stack overflow isn't really a code reviewing website

Comment: I don't get an error running this with python 2.7.13.

Answer (score 2):

While the `time.time()` portion of the code works for me, on `line 24` you can't use `^` to denote an exponent. In python you use `**`. As Nick pointed out below, `^` is the bitwise [exclusive or operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) in python.

Comment: I believe it's a bitwise exclusive or, not a logical or.